# How to get WTI Crude price in Excel stocks?

Tags: excel, office365

Office 365 Excel has this nice feature of getting stock data. However, I cannot figure out how to get the West Texas Intermediate (WTI) data. What is the ticker for WTI for Excel to recognize?

I have tried CLM20.NYM (The June 2020 WTI futures), CL, CL.NYM, WTI, WTI.NYM, ... nothing works

I am able to enter the Brent Crude Oil and Excel recognizes it, but I cannot figure out the WTI data

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with CL, the ticker Excel wants is `'@CL0Y` for **Light Sweet Crude Oil** (the old name of West Texas Intermediate) to get Excel to accept it add the ' in front of the @ sign